# Could not load Installation file : C:/Xampp/htdocs/public/install/install_step.php

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, mysql-workbench

I am very new in php I have existing PHP MVC project I so I install XAMPP server, Netbeans and  MySQL Workbench in Window 10 after that I try to run existing project I am getting error

**Could not load Installation file: C:/XamppNEw/htdocs/public/install/install_step.php**

how to fix it please help me

[image: Error Image]

Comment: have you done some research? google'd it?

Comment: @Vinny Thanks for your comment I searched but  didn't anything pls help me